# chrome doesn't seem to respect X-Frame-Options

Tags: apache, google-chrome, x-frame-options

I was working on a project and there is an iframe that opens in it.  It was refusing to open with the message:

Refused to display 'https://www.example.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'.

So, I updated X-Frame-Options to "SAMEORIGIN", but it still denies me in chrome.  I did a hard refresh, and I checked the headers from the server.  The headers indeed show "SAMEORIGIN" for X-Frame-Options.

I opened up firefox, and the page works fine.

Is Chrome caching the old X-Frame-Option value, even though it shows me the correct one?  If so, is there a way to get Chrome to forget about it?